# How can I use Regular Expression to convert String to different substring?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a text file containing lines, similar to these

```
000001 , Line 1 of text , customer 1 name
000002 , Line 2 of text , customer 2 name
000003 , Line 3 of text , customer 3 name
  =               =             =
  =               =             =
  =               =             =
000087 , Line 87 of text, customer 87 name
  =               =             =
  =               =             =
001327 , Line 1327 of text, customer 1327 name
  =               =             =
  =               =             =
  =               =             =
```

I can write a program that reads each line of the above file to convert it to the following format:

```
000001 , 1st Line , 1st Customer name
000002 , 2nd Line , 2nd Customer name
000003 , 3rd Line , 3rd Customer name
  =               =        =
  =               =        =
  =               =        =
000087 , 87th Line, 87th Customer name
  =               =        =
  =               =        =
001327 , 1327th Line, 1327th Customer name
  =               =        =
  =               =        =
  =               =        =
```

My Question: is there a straight forward method to achieve the same output using Regular expression?

[image]

I tried the following:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(\d{6}) , (Line \d+ of text) , (customer \d name)" 
Dim replacement As String = " $1 , $2 Line , $3 Customer name " 
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(my_input_file, replacement)
```

but the result is far from the desired output.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matching groups are to big. What you want to match are the numbers.

---

Replace `(\d{6}) , Line (\d+) of text , customer (\d+) name`

by `$1 , $2th Line , $3th Customer name`

---

Then replace `1th` by `1st`

---

Then replace `2th` by `2nd`

---

Then replace `3th` by `3rd`

---

I do not know if it was your intention to match a real cutomer name itself and replace it in another order ... was it?

---

Then you could use (with global and multiline flags)

`^(\d{6}) , Line (\d+) of text , ([^ ]+) (\d) ([^ ]+)$`

and replace with `$1 , $2th Line , $4th $3 $5`

---

**Tip:** I allways use http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test my patterns and experiment with them!

Answer (score 5):

Your regex captures too much. The groups should capture only digits:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(\d{6}) , Line (\d+) of text , customer (\d+) name"
```

Also, as you want to replace the numbers with ordinal numbers, you should rather use `String.Format` to do the formatting (line by line):

```
Dim match as Match = rgx.match(my_input_file_line)
Dim outputLine as String = String.Format(" {0} , {1} Line , {2} Customer name", _
    m.Groups(1).Value, GetOrdinal(m.Groups(2).Value), GetOrdinal(m.Groups(3).Value))
```

where `GetOrdinal` is a method that changes a string for number to an ordinal number.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for using regex? Maybe i have misuderstood the requirement, but it seems to be a fix format where only the first part matters, so you could use this simple query:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"folder\input_text.txt");
IEnumerable<string> result = lines
.Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0)
.Select(l => int.Parse(l.Split(',').First().Trim()))
.Select(num => string.Format("{0} , {1} Line , {1} Customer name"
    , num.ToString("D6")
    , num + (num == 1 ? "st" : num == 2 ? "nd" : "rd")));
```

You can use `File.WriteAllLines` to write the result to the output file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"folder\desired_output.txt", result);
```